# Image on the MainLayout page

Tags: blazor-server-side

I am trying to put my company logo on my blazor page in MainLayout page. MainLayout page exists in the shared directory any my logo image is in Images directory. Below is the structure:

[image]

This is what I have in my MainLayout.razor page:

```
<div class="main">
   
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="../Images/Logo.png" width="30" height="30" alt="">My company logo
        </a>
    </nav>

    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

I dont see the logo when I run the application. Below is the image of what I see:

[image]

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common html issue, not just with Blazor.  "../" in the source address means "up one level."  But it's not up one level in your Blazor folder-- it's up one level from the perspective of the browser.

Run your site in Chrome, and right-click "Inspect" to open the dev page, and again right-click "Inspect" where the image should be, and by looking around the markup, you should be able to see what path Chrome thinks you want it to display.  You will see that it's not the correct folder.

Try playing around with the prefix to see how it changes the expected image path:

- "/Images/Logo.png"
- "./Images/Logo.png"
- "~/Images/Logo.png"